# Показать объект в массиве

Tags: javascript

Я хочу, чтобы alert выводил **1, а не [object Object]**.

Как это исправить?

```js
let obj = {name:1};

let massive = [obj];

obj = null;

alert(massive[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте `alert(massive[0].name)` Будет выводить `1` =)

Comment: Благодарствую сударь =)